# is there any site to get imap Mail commands list?

Tags: imap, imaplib

i want to learn all commands using in IMAP.

1. fetch all mails
2. read particular mail
3. search particular mail
4. create folder/label

is there any site to get imap command list?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, read [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). The [IMAP wiki](http://www.imapwiki.org/ClientImplementation) also has plenty of resources for client developers.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to a server via telnet and issue the help command. 
Telnet server.com 110

Comment: My bad. IMAP is 143 and POP3 is 110